# Create a protected folder on USB Stick

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, ntfs, fat32

I like to have a protected folder on my USB stick with my name in it, so if someone finds it, they can return it to me. There will be no data inside, it's just a named folder on top of all other data.

I had this on my other stick, but don't remember how I did it. It was some kind of filesystem trick where Windows couldn't access the folder because there was another protected folder inside or something.

When I google for it, I keep finding lots of blog entries on how to create a folder with Windws keywords that are protected. But I don't want a folder named "AUX" or "COM", it should be a custom name.

I already tried to protected it with `cacls`, but it does not work on a FAT32 USB.
Reformatting to NTFS would be ok if required, as long as the stick stays compatible with Ubuntu, Windows 7 and PlayStation 3.

Note:
This doesn't have to ultimately safe, I just want a protected folder that can't be deleted easily

So any tips on how to achieve that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: TrueCrypt volume could be a partial solution - it will be protected, but easy to delete.

Comment: A format would wipe out the drive in all cases, so there's no way to truly protect your flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a folder with any name you want. Then inside that folder, create the "special" folder, for example, type try this in command prompt:

```
md "This is my folder"
cd "This is my folder"
md con\
```

Now, your folder "This is my folder" cannot be deleted.